# PHP artisan tinker, GROUP BY - aggregate NOT Working but working with SQL as Sql Query inside Management Studio

Tags: php, sql-server, laravel, tinker

I have a query

SQL Query
**SELECT YEAR(created_At) [YEAR], MONTH(created_at) [MONTH], COUNT(*) as Published_Articles 
FROM dbo.tasks
GROUP BY YEAR(created_At), MONTH(created_at)**

Which produces correct result when asked to run in Management Studio

Result

[image]

However, when I try to run the same query in laravel tinker, it doesn't run and it says year as an invalid column name but if you look at the query I am using correct alias. Not sure where I am going wrong and why it cannot output the same result as SQL Server Management studio.

tinker not accepting Alias

[image]

Can someone please give some direction, I am bit confused

Comment: Group by can’t use result column aliases. As you can see from the working query it’s the actual function that’s used in the grouping, not a column alias

Comment: Hi, for some reason the alias are working for Laracast guys, please have a look at the snip of the video where they use Alias  https://imgur.com/a/xGwsoMp